# How to create hierarchical urls within django app?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have multiple app based django project and within some apps url scheme getting complicated due to number of models. Hence I'm looking a way to make a hierarchical url structure **within the app**.

In my **project's urls file** I do the following.

```
from order import urls as order_urls
```

In the `order` app I have `urls.py` and `urls` directory which contains separate url patterns for each model as follows.

[image]
In the app's urls.py file I import the model's urls as follows.

```
from  urls import rental as rental_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^rental-request/', include(rental_urls)),
]
```

This gives me the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urls'`
If I put `__init__.py` it gives me circular import error.

I'm not sure this is the correct way/possible for my requirement. Anyone could explain the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: Note, you can include lists of patterns defined within the same urls.py; it doesn't have to be a separate module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a folder called `urls` (with an `__init__.py` file) as well as a file `urls.py` in the same folder will probably cause trouble to load the module `order.urls` from anywhere in your project. How does Python will know which file must be loaded ?

Consider this structure:

```
├── main.py
├── urls
│   └── __init__.py
└── urls.py
```

And this content for each file:

```
# urls/__init__.py
urlpatterns = "I'm in folder"

# urls.py
urlpatterns = "I'm in file"

# main.py
import urls
print(urls.urlpatterns)
```

When you run main.py, the result is:

```
% python main.py
I'm in folder
```

**Possible solutions :**
You may delete the `urls.py` and move its content to `urls/__init__.py`, or rename the folder `urls` to avoid conflicts and updates imports accordingly (in `urls.py`)